# Непонятное поведение программы при смене языка android

Tags: android, locale

В своем приложении я пытаюсь изменить язык runtime, то есть в процессе работы. Я уже задавал вопрос, но на него никто не ответил, поэтому я продолжил дальше самостоятельно разбираться с этим вопросом.

Задача стоит предельно четкая сделать полную поддержку нескольких языков приложением: что-бы на лету пересоздавалась активити с новым языком, и дальше выбранный язык сохранялся в настройках приложения, и при последующих запусках использовался этот сохраненный язык.

Что у меня на данный момент получилось сделать:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String countryCode = data.getStringExtra(CountrycodeActivity.RESULT_CONTRYCODE);
            String lang = "en";

            switch (countryCode) {
                case "English":
                    lang = "en";
                    LoginActivity.this.recreate();
                    break;
                case "Deutsch":

                    break;
                case "Русский":
                    lang = "ru";
                    LoginActivity.this.recreate();
                    break;
                case "Español":

                    break;


            }
            changeLang(lang);
        }
    }

    private void changeLang(String lang) {
        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return;
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        saveLocale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    private void saveLocale(String lang) {
        String langPref = "Language";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("def_loc", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(langPref, lang);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

с приведенного кода сверху можно понять, что у меня есть список необходимых мне языков. Нажимая на нужный язык, я автоматом пересоздаю активити с новым языком. Я проверил все ок, то есть выбираем нужный язык и дальше активити уже с необходимым языком. Дальше я пытаюсь сохранить нужный мне язык что-бы потом, даже если приложение закрыли (не свернули) я мог при запуске иметь уже заранее выбранный язык. Вот что я закинул в функцию `onCreate()`:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("def_loc", 0);
        String local = sp.getString("def_loc", "");
        if (!local.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, local, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            changeLang(local);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

у меня вроде все нормально, всплывающее уведомление показывает код языка, и по логике он должен сетиться на активити, но этого не происходит. Я вроде вызываю нужную функцию, но все-равно ничего не помогает.

### UPDATE

моя функция onCreate():

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sp = getSharedPreferences("def_loc", 0);
        String local = sp.getString("def_loc", "");
        changeLang(local);
        setContentView(activity_login);
```

теперь язык не меняется в активити на лету, теперь он вообще не меняется.

Может где-то протупил и чего-то не дописал? Надеюсь на вашу помощь))

Comment: проблем со сменой языка может быть много разных. Есть хорошая статья на эту тему с примером на github https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758

Comment: да я видел эту статью, но я использовал другой источник - http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-Change-Language-in-Android-Application-Programmatically/9197/.

Comment: Попробуйте `setContentView` вызывать после установки языка.

Comment: вроде все работает, но почему-то не сетится язык после закрытия приложения

Comment: @Suvitruf, вы имеете в виду во время повторного запуска, или сразу после выбора?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko в `onCreate`.

Comment: а с этим сетером что делать `setContentView(activity_login);`?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko ну вот его вызывать после установки языка.

Comment: сейчас обновлю вопрос, потому-что походу я что-то не то делаю)

Comment: единственное что у меня на данный момент получилось, так это менять язык на лету, если использовать мой метод `onCreate()` где я вызываю функцию изменения языка, в которой я пересоздаю активити, то у меня зацикливается программа.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko обновил ответ

Comment: @McDaggen, короче не получается у меня пока что при последующем открытии приложения, устанавливать нужный мне язык.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя в методе `onCreate` значение по умолчанию пустое `""`.

```
String local = sp.getString("def_loc", "");
```

Вместо пустых кавычек, нужно указать значение по умолчанию.

И вместо `recreate()` наверное лучше вызывать это:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

P.S. Уже советовал тебе, советую еще раз, не давай переменным такие имена как, `local`, сделай `strLocal` или как-то иначе.

Comment: что то у меня опять зацикливается программа, даже не знаю в чем может быть проблема. Вроде все сделал так как нужно, и все равно цикл идет, может в `onCreate()` нужно что-то другое вызывать? или пусть программа считает сколько раз пересоздается активити, не могу даже придумать что может быть не так